# Using React components with css modules, is there a way to affect a parent component's child's class (a cousin once or twice removed) on hover?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

Code layout is essentially as follows.

```
//ComponentA.tsx

import styles from './ComponentA.module.css'

<ComponentA className="styles.componentA">
    <div className="styles.componentB">
    <ComponentC>
</ComponentA>
```

```
//ComponentA.module.css

.componentA {
}
.componentB {
}
```

```
//ComponentC.module.css
import styles from './ComponentC.module.css'

export const ComponentC: FC<Props> = ({settings}) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="styles.componentD" />
    </div>
    )
}
```

```
//ComponentC.module.css

.componentD {
}
```

When the div that has the className of `styles.componentD` is hovered, I'd like the div with `className="styles.componentB"` to have its style changed. I've tried various things like `.componentA:has(.componentC:hover) ~ .componentB {}` in the `ComponentA.module.css` to no avail.

What sort of solutions exist besides `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` with state management through prop drilling or redux?

Answer (score -1):

affect a cousin component's style when a specific element in another component is hovered, you can use CSS variables and adjacent sibling selectors.

ComponentA.module.css:

```
.componentA {
  --hovered: 0;
}

.componentA:hover {
  --hovered: 1;
}
```

ComponentC.module.css:

```
.componentD:hover ~ .componentB {
  background-color: var(--hovered, 0) ? red : initial;
}
```

This approach uses CSS variables to pass hover state information between components and the adjacent sibling selector to apply styles to the target component